# Cosmos DB Emulator Excessive CPU usage

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Since upgrading to version 2.14.5 of the Cosmos DB emulator, I'm seeing high CPU usage by what appears to be the tray icon process (Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Emulator.exe). See below, using up most of a CPU core constantly on an Intel i9-12900K. This was an upgrade from 2.14.4 on Windows 11.

Anyone from the emulator team know what might be going on? Seems like the process is doing something silly, given the system is otherwise quiet and the process is not actually doing anything related to serving requests.

Also worth noting is that opening the "About Azure Cosmos Emulator" dialog immediately drops the CPU usage to 0. When closing the dialog, usage jumps back.

[image]

Comment: This probably fits better in one of the Azure-specific support channels, since it's a potential issue specific to one of their tools.

Comment: What might be the best channel for this?

Comment: Probably the [Cosmos DB forum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/topics/azure-cosmos-db.html) in Microsoft Q&A.

Comment: Hey Noah, can you click the smiley face in the upper right corner in Data Explorer and put your information in there? That sends an email to the emulator team. I think they're aware of this. Thanks.

Comment: Good call Mark, I've seen that so many times I forgot it was there :). The actual link didn't redirect to opening an email for me, but for posterity the email is: cdbportalfeedback@microsoft.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to have been fixed with release of version [2.14.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator-release-notes#2146-march-7-2022)